# How to cleanly turn a ResultPropertyValueCollection of bytes back into a string

Tags: arrays, powershell, encoding, type-conversion, openldap

I'm running a query against an openlap instance to pull some SSH keys, but they're coming back as byte arrays wrapped in System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection objects, which I'm having trouble finding a clean way to decode.

The query I'm running is simple enough:

```
$domain = 'LDAP://ldap.local:636/dc=local'
$auth = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Anonymous
$root = new-object -Typename System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($domain,$null,$null,$auth)
$query = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root, "uid=$uid", @("uid","sshPublicKey"))
$results = $query.findall()
```

But when I take the results and try to feed them into a converter, it gets unhappy:

```
$enc = [system.text.encoding]::UTF8
$enc.GetString($results.properties.sshpublickey)

Cannot convert argument "bytes", with value: "System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection", for "GetString" to type "System.Byte[]": "Cannot convert value "System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection" to type
"System.Byte[]". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Byte[]" value of type "System.Byte[]" to type "System.Byte".""
At line:1 char:1
+ $enc.GetString($results.properties.sshpublickey)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Unless I feed it the individual bytes one at a time:

```
foreach ($byte in $results.properties.sshpublickey) {$enc.getstring($byte)}
```

...and that just feels *ugly* - is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing, or is this just the madness of powershell?  Also, does anyone know *why* these SSH keys are being returned as arrays of bytes rather than just text?  Is there a setting I could change with my query or within the openldap instance I'm querying to just force it to provide the text in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: try `$enc.GetString($results.properties.sshpublickey[0])`. this is no "powershell madness" btw. this is how adsi works

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Is the assumption that this could be a multivalued object and so it gets returned in a collection?  Do you know where in the ADSI documentation I could dig up more information about this behavior?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.resultpropertyvaluecollection?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult?view=windowsdesktop-7.0